# Android Card Layout: Draw a line spanning multiple cards

Tags: android, cardlayout

I am using Android card layout throughout my application. On one page "order history" (see attached image) I have to draw a line spanning multiple cards. How can I achieve this.

[image: Order History Screen with card layout]

Comment: 1>create one more layer in top of card view
2> create separator with image which has thin line which you want as in image and create same line in card view to reduce creating extra view  layer in top of card view.

Comment: @tynn Well, I am the designer and I want to design it this way :)

Comment: Just saying that I'm not aware of a possibility to do this well. And it seems contradicting material design. Are you using a static layout or a `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I am using `RecyclerView`